# mudar de cor depois que uma página foi visitada usando Bootstrap

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

parece que fazer isso não surge efeito:

```
a:visited{
   color: #red;
}
```

Existe uma outra possibilidade de saber que página a pessoa já visitou?

Estou usando `php`

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando ***cookies*** é possível verificar se uma página foi visitada.

Por exemplo:

```
setcookie("visitado", "1" /*, time() + 3600 */);
```

Onde o terceiro parâmetro que foi omitido, configura para o cookie expirar em uma hora, quando omitido o cookie só é válido até fechar o navegador.

Lembre-se que o cookie deve ser criado antes de qualquer saída, então é mais adequado criá-lo no início do código.

No seu arquivo de layout você faria algo como:

```
<a class="<?= key_exists("visitado", $_COOKIE) ? 'visited' : '' ?>">Página inicial</a>
```

E no seu arquivo css:

```
.visitado {
  color: red;
}
```